# Explanation of beamer theme matrix

Tags: beamer, themes

I am trying for themes given in [the beamer theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix) but when I am changing the theme of my presentation like `PaloAlto` or `CambridgeUs` it was changing accordingly but when I was trying with the `beetle` or `whale` or any of the theme given in top row of that matrix it was coming with the error as follow:

> ! LaTeX Error: File
>   `beamerthemebeetle.sty' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed,
>   or enter new name. (Default extension:
>   sty)
>
> Enter file name:

Can anyone tell me where can be the problem ?

Answer (score 17):

There's a difference between beamer themes and beamer color themes. The beamer themes are named after cities. The complete color themes happen to have names of flying animals. Inner color themes happen to have flower names. The outer color themes happen to be sea-animal names. For further details, refer to Section 17 *Colors* of the `beameruserguide`. You can use something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

that is not a general theme! it is a color theme and has to changed with `\usecolortheme{...}`